# Filter lists with HTML-form

Tags: javascript, html-form-web-part

Today i use HTML-Form web part to connect to the list in question. I then use the following code to filter/sort:

```
<div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) _SFSUBMIT_">
<select name="filter">
<option value="">Pick one</option>
<option value="Department 1">Department 1</option>
<option value="Department 2">Department 2</option>
<option value="Department 3">Department 3</option>
<option value="Department 4">Department 4</option>
<input type="button" value="show" onclick="javascript:_SFSUBMIT_"/>
</select>
</div>
```

When users are filtering the lists, it requires 3 clicks from them.
First, open the dropdown list, then select a value and finally, click on the "show"-button.

I want to reduce the number of clicks to one. by using buttons instead. It is possible? Or is the connection between web part and list the only way for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

try the `onclick`event for the `<input>` tag: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

So:

```
<div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) _SFSUBMIT_">
<input value="Department 1" onclick='javascript:_SFSUBMIT_' type="button">Department 1</option>
<input value="Department 2" onclick='javascript:_SFSUBMIT_' type="button">Department 2</option>
<input value="Department 3" onclick='javascript:_SFSUBMIT_' type="button">Department 3</option>
<input value="Department 4" onclick='javascript:_SFSUBMIT_' type="button">Department 4</option>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution reduced the number of clicks, but I want to get away from the dropdown. I belive buttons to be more user friendly.

Comment: see my edits. Using inputs for buttons

Comment: That code does not work, I'll try to see if I can modify it and make it work. Thank you for taking the time

Comment: depends on how you are trying to connect with the webpart in question.